# How to make gradle ignore c++ files?

Tags: android, android-ndk

My app uses JNI to do some native work, and all c++ files are in /src/main/jni with

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
       path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

in my build.gradle.

All works fine until all my colleagues ask me to make the jni a library so they can build the apk without downloading a ndk.

So I use ndk-build and libraries are generated in src/main/libs. But when I build the apk, gradle says:

```
> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
  Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
  Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
```

What I want is to keep the source code in jni, build the library manually, and make the Gradle ignore the cpp files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wrap it like this:

```
if (ndkDirectory) {
  externalNativeBuild {
     ndkBuild {
       path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
  }
}
```

But if AS can find the cpp files in the standard location src/main/jni it will still complain, and I disable the NDK compile tasks in **build.gradle** in the very end, after the **android** block is closed.

```
tasks.all {
  task ->
    if (!android.NdkDirectory) {
      if (task.name.endsWith('Ndk') || task.name.startsWith('externalNativeBuild')) {
        task.enabled = false  // Android Studio will complain about c++ files when NDK is not installed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guessed that only android block can read the ndkDirectory varaible, so how NdkDirectory in tasks block get the ndkDirectory value?

Comment: *only android block can read the ndkDirectory variable* - Correct. Fixed now.

Comment: @ Alex Cohn, got inspired by you code, I came up a way to handler the compiler complain problem, I'v post it as an answer, you are wolcome to review.

Answer (score 0):

Got inspired by @Alex Cohn, I came up with an idea:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        if (!android.ndkDirectory) {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/libs"]
            jni.srcDirs = []
        } else {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}

if (ndkDirectory) {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}
```

`jni.srcDirs = []` will make the compiler to ignore jni file.

Comment: I usually prefer not to mess with the **sourceSets**, because even if I don't want to run **ndk-build**, I still want to see the C++ sources. But this is a question of taste, your approach will work.